# Resetting/Restart Rxjs Stream on form submit

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular-observable

I have an input field which when submitted makes a http call and then plots a graph. When I click on any node of graph, same http call is made and results are appended to the previous results and graph is updated. It is working fine till here. I am using scan operator to update my resultset. Now, what I want is to reset the resultset (ie - return new original response) whenever I am submitting the input form and append to resultset when graph node is clicked. Any ideas on how this can be achieved? Mainly how can I reset this stream on form submit? Or how can I show new data on form submit and updated data on node click

> ```
> Here linkingDetailsByAccount$ makes the http call and gets the data from the server.
> this.linkingDetailsByAccountSubject.next(account);
> ```
>
> Same code is called on node click as well as on form submit which then activates my stream.

```
graph$ = this.linkingDetailsByAccount$.pipe(
pluck('graph'),
scan((linkedDetails, adjacency) => {
  const { nodes: linkedNodes = [], edges: linkedEdges = [] } = linkedDetails;
  const { nodes: newNodes = [], edges: newEdges = [] } = adjacency;


  const updatedNodes = differenceBy(newNodes, linkedNodes, 'id');
  const updatedEdges = differenceWith(
    newEdges,
    linkedEdges,
    (newEdge: VisEdge, existingEdge: VisEdge) => newEdge.from === existingEdge.to
  );
  const allNodes = [...linkedNodes, ...updatedNodes];
  const allEdges = [...linkedEdges, ...updatedEdges];

  return {
    nodes: allNodes,
    edges: allEdges
  };
}, {} as NodesEdges)
);
```

Appreciate any inputs on this.

Thanks,

Vatsal

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Updated answer when I received more details from OP.

How I would do it is turn it into a mini Redux like state manager.

So the `scan` operator should take in functions or event objects.

First you want to store the first initial state from the initial HTTP call you make. You will use this object to reset your state on form submission.

Then create a graphEvents subject.

```
interface UpdateGraphEvent {
  type: 'Update';
  account: any;
}

interface ResetGraphEvent {
  type: 'Reset';
  account: any;
}

type GraphEvent = UpdateGraphEvent | ResetGraphEvent;

this.graphEvents$ = new Subject<GraphEvent>();
```

Then you can use your new graphEvents$ subject to replace uses of linkingDetailsByAccountSubject.

```
// When you want to update with new data.
this.graphEvent$.next({type: 'Update', account: account});

// when you want to reset with initial data.
this.graphEvent$.next({type: 'Reset', account: this.initialAccount});
```

Then use it in your stream.

```
graph$ = this.graphEvent$.pipe(
pluck('graph'),
scan((linkedDetails, event: GraphEvent) => {
  if (event.type === 'Reset') {
    return {
      nodes: event.account.nodes,
      edges: event.account.edges,
    }
  }

  const { nodes: linkedNodes = [], edges: linkedEdges = [] } = linkedDetails;
  const { nodes: newNodes = [], edges: newEdges = [] } = event.account;


  const updatedNodes = differenceBy(newNodes, linkedNodes, 'id');
  const updatedEdges = differenceWith(
    newEdges,
    linkedEdges,
    (newEdge: VisEdge, existingEdge: VisEdge) => newEdge.from === existingEdge.to
  );
  const allNodes = [...linkedNodes, ...updatedNodes];
  const allEdges = [...linkedEdges, ...updatedEdges];

  return {
    nodes: allNodes,
    edges: allEdges
  };
}, {} as NodesEdges)
);
```

The `graphEvent$` will be a Subject that emits those events (GraphEvent).

Comment: I think I may not be very much clear in the question. When I say reset, I don't want to just return empty arrays. I just don't want it to append it to older results. So it should work let go of the older result set and start again from new result set and

Comment: @Vatsal what is the reason for wanting to reset the stream? What benefit will it give you?

Comment: I have an input field which when submitted makes a http call and then plots a graph. When I click on any node of graph, same http call is made and results are appended to the previous results and graph is updated. It is working fine till here. I am using scan operator to update my resultset. Now, what I want is to reset the resultset whenever I am submitting the input form and append to resultset when graph node is clicked. Any ideas on how this can be achieved? Mainly how can I reset this stream on form submit?

Comment: @Vatsal that's the same as your original question with no new info. Sorry that I am struggling to interpret what you need excatly.

When you say 'reset the resultset', that sounds like you just want to reset your stream to the original value it started with, which is an empty object?

Comment: Ok, Firstly when user submits the form with an account - I get some data from server and plot it in a graph. Now whenever I click any graph node same stream gets me data again and I add it to the older resultset. This is fine because these all accounts are related. Now, if I want to do a fresh search by inputting data again in the input field - How can I do a fresh search? With the current setup, it just keeps appending to the previous resultset. I want it to append when graph node is clicked and start afresh when form is submitted

Comment: @Vatsal doesn't my solution solve that?
It'll emit the empty data on the stream

Comment: May be I am not understanding it properly, but you have replaced linkingDetailsByAccount$ with graphEvent$. linkingDetailsByAccount$ is the stream that's getting me the account details. Moreover, in case of reset it will just return me object with empty arrays as nodes and edges. I would like it to return my original response. However, how will I be passing both account id and event type at the same time? I am new with Rx. So please bear with me :)

Comment: To be precise, I want to return original response on form submit - not empty data. Empty data will render nothing. I want a new graph on form submit

Comment: I will check and will let you know

Comment: This looks nice. Clever